# while (fgets (buffer, 1024, fp) != NULL) in while (fgets (buffer, 1024, fp) != NULL)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
include <getopt.h>

#define DEFAULT_STRING_NUM 10  /*default number lines */
#define MAXLEN 2000            /* max number of the array */
#define MAXLINES 1024          /* max number lines  */

char *lineptr[MAXLINES];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;
    int c;
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char *arr[2000];
    int len = 0;
    char buffer[1024] = {'\0'};
    char *str;
    int i = 0, j, k;

    c = getopt (argc, argv, "n:");

    if (c == 'n')
        sscanf ( argv[2], "%d", &n);
    else
        n = 10;

    fp = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
    while (fgets (buffer, 1024, fp) != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen (buffer);
        str = malloc (len+1); 
        strcpy (str, buffer); 
        if (arr[i%n] )
        {
            free (arr[i%n]);
            arr[i%n] = NULL;
        }

        arr[i%n] = str;
        i++;
        memset (buffer, '\0', 1024);
    }

    k = i - 1;

    for (j=k; j<n+k; j++)
        printf ("%s", arr[j%n]); 

    return 0;
}
```

I am struggling with segmentation fault on

```
while (fgets (buffer, 1024, fp) != NULL)
```

Comment: You aren't checking whether `fp` is valid. How do you know whether it opened the file or not?

Comment: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                         
_IO_fgets (buf=0x7fffffffe750 "", n=1024, fp=0x0) at iofgets.c:50            
50      iofgets.c: No such file or directory.

Comment: `fp=0x0` tells you that `fp` is `NULL`, which means the file wasn't opened. You need to handle that.

Comment: you saying do not need to include fp ?

Comment: That is not what I'm saying at all. You need to check the return value of `fopen` to make sure it actually opened the file.

Comment: Most likely the current directory is not where input.txt is located.

Comment: yes the input.txt is located  to a directory given from professor, different location

Answer (score 0):

fgets() causes a segmentation fault because the previous call to fopen() is failing. Check the value returned from fopen(). If it's NULL, don't try to do the I/O. Instead, look at errno to see why the file couldn't be opened.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
fp = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL)
{
   perror("failed to open file ");
   exit(1);
}
```

THis will tell you why the file failed to open